# From where do the bubbles come from in an aerated tap?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, water, bubbles

It is common knowledge that when the opening of a tap has many holes, the water flows out as a stream of bubbles.

But if you open the tap slowly, the water flow is laminar without any bubbles at first. Only after opening the tap to a certain point, bubbles start appearing (almost out of nowhere) near the opening of the tap and increase in number till the whole of the water flow is filled with bubbles. You can hopefully see this transition point in the video below.

[image: Transistion]

Why do these bubbles form, and where do they come from?

Note that my question is not about the [mixing of air due to turbulent flow](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504455/why-does-water-change-from-transparent-to-opaque-when-it-comes-out-of-a-tap). It is about the *creation of air bubbles* inside the water flow (if that makes any sense).

Short, to-the-point answers are welcome as always.

Comment: I think that the reason is right the mixing in of air that you would like to exclude.

Comment: mixing of air from _where_ exactly?

Comment: From around the tap/aerator

Comment: Well, then what role does the aerator play here?  Wouldn't we get bubble streams without aerators?

Comment: Are you familiar with the simple water stream vacuum pump? The same mechanism should be at work. Sorry because advertising is not the purpose but at the moment I have only found this, as I have forgot the exact hydrodynamical term or principle to search for.... https://www.gea.com/en/products/pumps-valves-flow-components/jet-pumps/liquid-jet-vacuum-pump.jsp

Comment: Many aerators have visible air intake slits, but not yours, by appearance. There may be a gap for air intake around the rim of the add-on  mesh assembly, so the air (you don't need much of it!) comes from below, outside the reconstituting fragmented water stream.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Oh, I see now. There is indeed a gap between the mesh and the tap's inner surface. That solves it, I guess

Comment: See my answer to the second question in this series, which explains where the air comes from.